# autocomplete jquery not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

```
<html>
 <head>        
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>      
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">      
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">        
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.14/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css">


<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
     $(window).load(function(){
        $("#auto").autocomplete({ 
           source: ['hi', 'bye', 'foo', 'bar'],
           change: function (event, ui) {
                   if (ui.item) {
                     $("#message").text("user selected " + ui.item.value + "     from list.");            
                   } else {
                     $("#message").text("user entered " + this.value);
                   }
            }
        });    
    });    
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="auto" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
  <span id="message">user selected bye from list.</span>
  <ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1; top: 22px; left: 0px; display: none; width: 193px;"><li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">bye</a></li><li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">bar</a></li></ul></body></html>
```

I want to change source of jquery to abc.php . It has to take data from database . How to change autocomplte above code . How to take autocomple date from database. Please Help me to resolve this issue .

Comment: Doesn't seem like you've tried much.

Comment: Check [this](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote)

Answer (score 0):

You need `select` event instead of `change`

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({ 
    source: ['hi', 'bye', 'foo', 'bar'],
    select: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.item) {
            $("#message").text("user selected " + ui.item.value + " from list.");            
        } else {
            $("#message").text("user entered " + this.value);
        }
    }
});
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tLthamxh/1/)

[See API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select)

Answer (score 0):

Try This to get data from your PHP datasource:

```
$( "#auto" ).autocomplete({
        source: "abc.php",
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            console.log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the example on the jquery ui page (https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote), you simply have to change the source to:

```
source: "abc.php"
```

Two things to keep in mind:

1. Autocomplete sends the parameter named `term` to your url, which contains the input value of the automplete.
2. Autocomplete expects as a response a list of objects, which have two properties: `label`(used for display) and `value`(used to identify the displayed value). If `label` is not present, it will use `value` instead.

Comment: whats is search.php in this program. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote . I written something in search.php but its not working . How to write search.php . example plz

Comment: You need to get the parameter $_REQUEST["term"], and use its value to search for the items you are looking for (e.g. in a database).